# What happens to system agent tables on SQL Server Restart?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What happens to the system agent tables whenever the database server is restarted?  More specifically, does SQL Server assign new job_ids to each job when they are run after the reset, or does the job_id stay the same?

Comment: Do you mean the SQL Server Agent tables in msdb?

Comment: Yes. Specifically the msdb.dbo.sysjobs table

Comment: It's faster to test this than to ask it on StackOverflow :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job ID is assigned at the time of [job creation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx) and remains static after that point.